# 600k rows csv file parsing / formating with python EXTREMELY slow

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

My first question here since i started with python a couple days ago.
I've great experience with VBA and Matlab, but I'm currently trying python as an exercise and because of the larger (is it?) quant community behind it.

I searched quite a lot before asking here, i even used some code snippets which i found here from other users while doing mine (thanks all of you).

The thing is, I'm reading a tick data csv that is ~630k rows long (15mb) so i can extract its third column (last ticks / deals) and them create a structure (matlab lingo) for them, a column vector of all the ticks in DataFrame format so i can compute their pct_change (pandas).

I let it run overnight for about 6 hours and it was still @ ~150k/630k 
I'm sure that I'm doing something that is extremely inefficient.

I'm currently using spyder , running on windows 7, 4gb ram, i3 core, not really under heavy load.

Here is the code:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
created on Sun Jan 03 12:59:25 2016
@author: eduardo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

import pandas as pd
import csv as csv
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

path = "C:\Users\eduardo\.xy\startups"
data = "C:\Users\eduardo\.xy\startups\INDV14.CSV"

delimeters = [' ', ';'] # matrix [1,2]

unique = '[]'  # empty struct ?
close = [] # empty matrix for later use

with open(data) as data: # data = csv
    for row in data: # counter to loop for inside csv
        for cols in data: # another counter for separating columns now
            for d in delimeters:cols = unique.join(cols.split(d))
            # last for loop does not need ":" ? 
            # from d to d+n, step 1
            # splits columns using "d" separators defined above
            # joins them after splitting, by a "[]" separator "space" ?
            row = cols.split(unique) # row = for each row splitted
            close.append(row[2]) # call third column of each (row) 
            # fill the empty matrix created above (close) row by row
            # with it up with a column vector of my 3rd col of the CSV
            ticks = map(int, close) # coverts strings to integers
            # format the column vector above to pandas DataFrame format
            deals = pd.DataFrame(ticks)
            # call pct_change function of pandas 
            daily_returns = deals.pct_change(periods=1)
            print(daily_returns)
    data.close() # closes csv file 

    # creates a new file ("W"rite), returns.csv
    dataCSV = open('returns.csv', 'w') 
    for line in daily_returns: # de for each line in the daily returns struct
        dataCSV.write(line) # writes them in the new csv file 
    dataCSV.close() # closes new file

    datetime.now() - startTime # time counter
```

csv format:

```
20140801 105159;57085;5
20140801 105206;57085;5
```

Comment: Can you post what the first few lines of your csv look like, also you're incrementally growing your df which is non-performant, if you just want the 3rd col you can just do `df = pd.read_csv(data, usecols=[2])`

Comment: sure, thanks for the reply! im editing the original post so i can show the format of the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pull just the third column, you can do it a lot simpler,use the csv lib and split on the semi-colon and use the second element which will be equivalent to splitting the third column used in your code :

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
with open(data) as data: # data = csv
    for ith in map(itemgetter(1), csv.reader(data, delimiter=";")):
        print(ith)
```

While would output:

```
57085
57085
```

In your own code you create the DF's in the loop so you don't actually store any data bar the last call so even if it did finish you would have basically no data to write. If you really want a Dataframe split on the semi-colon and extract the second column `df = pd.read_csv(data,sep=";",usecols=[1], header=None)`, which would give you:

```
   1
0  57085
1  57085
```

Also `unique = '[]'  # empty struct ?` also creates a string, `unique.join(cols.split(d))` joins all the data together separated by "[]" and then you  `row = cols.split(unique)` which is exactly what you have before when you `cols.split(d)`.

Also if you wanted an array of just the second column you could use [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt(data, usecols=[1], delimiter=";")

print(arr)
```

Which would give you:

```
[57085.  57085.]
```

Or if you wanted the percent change:

```
pct_chnge = np.diff(arr) / arr[:-1]
```

If you want to use the full Dataframe to incorporate the dates to use in getting the percent change per day etc. :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";", header=None,parse_dates=[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @Padraic Cunningham ,I've just tested your code here inside my mini framweork:

`import pandas as pd
import csv 
from operator import itemgetter

data = "C:\Users\eduardo\.xy\startups\INDV14.CSV"
ticks = []

with open(data) as data: # data = csv
    for ith in map(itemgetter(1), csv.reader(data, delimiter=";")):
        ticks.append(ith)
        intticks = map(int,ticks)`

and i guess that what makes it really slow for me is the "transform" from `string` to `int` using `map`

Comment: @EduardoGonzatti, `for ith in map(int,map(itemgetter(1),csv.reader(data, delimiter=";"))):` would give you ints, if you are using python2 you would use `itertools.izip`, do you want actually Dataframe? I also see you don't use close anywhere, what do you want to do  with that?

Comment: @PadriacCunningham, actually, im only using the DataFrame because of the `pct_return` from pandas, so i could just create an array (column vector) of returns
  
edit: i just ran the code using your last line `ith in map(int,map(itemgetter(1), csv.reader(data, delimiter=";"))):` and it was completed in some 300ms ... impressive.. what was taking me > 10hrs.. 
do you know why is that ? I mean, the only difference was not calling `map` again, and using it since the first call\definition of the `ith`

Comment: @EduardoGonzatti,  Ah ok, I see you actually use close in the loop assigning ticks to it it and creating the DF, are you still creating the DF in the loop? As far as the improvement goes I am not sure why it would take so long just because we did not also  map  to int, in your own code there were a lot of unnecessary steps in the parsing and continually creating the DF each time would have been expensive.

Comment: @PadriacCunningham , Thanks, now I see that my code shows how bad I am at python so far :)

Comment: @EduardoGonzatti, no worries, I don't think too many of us start out writing perfect code in a new language, I am pretty sure your python is better than my  matlab. I added a few different ways to create the DF and a numpy array of just the data from the third column. If you want to consider the percent change on a daily basis you would need to use the date column

Answer (score 1):

I think this will just work if you tell pandas to parse your dates and pass the separator:

```
In [7]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""20140801 105159;57085;5
20140801 105206;57085;5"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=None, parse_dates=[0])
df

Out[7]:
                    0      1  2
0 2014-08-01 10:51:59  57085  5
1 2014-08-01 10:52:06  57085  5
```

So in your case just this should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, parse_dates=[0], sep=';')
```

You can then write it back out as a csv:

```
df.to_csv('returns.csv')
```

You can see that pandas has correctly sniffed the dtypes:

```
In [8]:
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
1    2 non-null int64
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2)
memory usage: 64.0 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks , I've just tried your code, but got the following error:

`df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', header=None, parse_dates=[0])

TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: Did you try this: `df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, parse_dates=[0], sep=';')` ignore the `io.StringIO` bit this is just my code loading your csv

Comment: thank you very much, 
i see that i still have LOTS to learn about the language when i look at your scripting , that "sniffing function" that the `pandas` have can be really useful for formating, i didnt know it was capable of!

Answer (score 0):

thanks all of you who responded:

here is how it ended up after your help:

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Created on Mon Jan 04 09:21:10 2016
@author: eduardo
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""

from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

import pandas as pd
import csv 
from operator import itemgetter

data = "C:\Users\eduardo\.xy\startups\INDV14.CSV" # address
ticks = [] # calling empty matrix

with open(data) as data: # data = original csv
    # for i(n) in first column after ";" in the open csv, "str" to "int"  
    for ith in map(int,map(itemgetter(1), csv.reader(data, delimiter=";"))):
        # call empy matrix shell above and fill it row by row with "int"s
        ticks.append(ith)
        data.close() # close csv file so it doesnt get stuck

# format matrix above ("ticks) to pandas DF format
prcnt_chng_df = pd.DataFrame(ticks)
# use pandas percent change (period=1) function for above DF with padding
prcnt_chng = prcnt_chng_df.pct_change(periods=1, fill_method='pad')
# print above structure of pct changes starting on the 2nd row
# no indexing since i dont need them and it would make the file bigger
print((prcnt_chng)[1:].to_csv('indv14_rets.csv', index=False))

timer = datetime.now() - startTime
print(timer) # counter`
```

i managed to get what i wanted so i can now call upon this new csv file into some other scripts in order to calculate the sprectral density of tick by tick returns of a future contract that happened during a whole month.

all of it done in `0:00:02.996000`

best regards